# Do you know any Chart Management Example?

Tags: web-applications

I'm stuck at designing an user interface for defining dynamic charts which are using recordset for databinding.

i dont need charting application or api, i need admin UI to control them

Do you know any good example of chart management application? or any suggestion for developing one?

Comment: You will have to define what you mean by "Chart Management". Your question cannot be answered as it stands now.

Comment: by chart management, i mean, an user interface where you can define, chart type, series values and labels, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Look at this realtime 3D web chart: http://www.parsec.hu/Chart/
It is flash that you can embed  with using a rich configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... one of those "just make everything easy" requirements :)

Maybe take a look at Google Analytics? It has a lot of controls over it's charting... though it is not an open ended graph anything anyway you want solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried two different charting systems

[Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) & [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)

Google Charts dynamically generates an image of the chart, whereas fusion is a flash based chart.

Also, because google charts uses a url as input your data is limited to the length of a url.

Hope this helps

Comment: you see, i dont need charting application or api, i need admin UI to control them

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET, the Telerik charting controls are quite nice and simple to bind a dataset to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in Google Chart API but can't access the web (e.g. intranet application), you can look at [Eastwood Charts](http://www.jfree.org/eastwood).

Answer (score 0):

Flex charting is nice.

Google and Yahoo have great libraries too.